# Enormous, constant memory consumption using VP9 codec in FFMPEG C++

Tags: ffmpeg, video-capture, webm, vp9

Using:
https://github.com/ash3D/VideoRecorder
Wrapped with:
https://github.com/ash3D/UEVideoRecorder

I added the VP9 codec to the "**FindEncoder**" function of the CVideoRecorder (part of the **VideoRecorder** repository). Using VP9 codec works generally, however the memory consumption is enormous and within a good 30 seconds, the memory usage goes up from 3GB to 6GB, upon which (round about) FFMPEG throws out of memory errors and aborts the encoding process. I started up the Diagnostics Tool of Visual Studio and it told me that **avcodec.dll** is holding all the memory, which is not released until the encoding is terminated (peacefully). The function within which the allocating call is executed is the CVideoRecorder::Encode() function, which inside it calls avcodec_send_frame().

H264 and HVENC work fine with a constant memory consumption of around 300MB.

I tried setting various settings on the VP9 codec like the bitrate, cfr and quality, none of which changed the behavior in any to me recognizable way.

Comment: Turns out VP9 is just incredible much slower than H.264. Okay then.

Comment: With the ffmpeg cli, by default, VP9 uses one thread. One has to add `-thread X` to init X threads. Don't know if this is the issue here.